# Apply a simple string to string transformation during deserialization

Tags: java, jackson, spring-data-rest

Is there a simple to way to apply a custom logic transformation on the value of a specific key during bean deserialization ?

Concrete example, i receive the following json:

```
{password: "1234"}
```

and want a special hash function applied to the password value when deserializing :

```
User [password: "6265b22b66502d70d5f004f08238ac3c"]
```

I know i could use a setter `User.setPassword()` and apply the hash transformation here but the transformation need to make use of "Service" classes which are not available in the context of an Entity (bad use of dependency injection..). This transformation must be made outside of the entity code.

Using a custom Deserializer for `User` class seems to be overkill for just one attribute too.

Comment: You could use the annotation *@JsonSerialize* and *@JsonDeserialize* to set a specific class that implement the specific interface. So you could put all the serialization/deserialization in those classes.

Comment: @JsonDeserialize looks promising but i can't figure how to use it for now. i'll take a look more in depth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the annotation to define a custom serializer/deserializer for the bean propery.

Here is an example of a bean where you define your custom serializer/deserializer classes:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;

public class User {

    @JacksonXmlProperty
    private String login;

    @JacksonXmlProperty
    @JsonSerialize(using=your.class.package.PasswordSerializer.class)
    @JsonDeserialize(using=your.class.package.PasswordDeserializer.class)
    private String password;
    // ... 
}
```

And here the custo, serializer example:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.ser.ToXmlGenerator;

import java.io.IOException;

public class PasswordSerializer extends JsonSerializer<String> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(String s, JsonGenerator jg, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

         // do your staff here.

    }
}
```

You just need to implement an interface, and you could do in the proper package.

The deserializer is similar.

Comment: Thanks, your answer got me on the way. But i need to solve another point. I am in a Spring context and need to inject services on the Deserializer class.

Comment: @tiben This is not a problem in Spring, you could implement the interfaces in a Spring Component and inject the beans/components you need.

Comment: Juste made a test and can't use `@Autowired` on MyDeserializer class. Despite the use of @Component, It results in a NullPointException because when using with @JsonDeserialize(using=MyDeserializer.class), i presume a `new` instance of my Deserializer is instanciated outside of the dependency injection mechanism of spring. But overhaul i think this is another question so i accept your answer because it resolves a big part of my issue.

Comment: @tiben right, sorry. Your case it's a bit complicated for that. But I think you could have access to the SpringContext (not sure which version or package of spring you're using) and directly get the Component, you need.